# Randomly displaying strings -

Tags: android, arrays, string, random

I have a set of strings labeled st1, st2, st3, etc...until st9.  I want to have a method that randomly shows one of those strings based off a randomly generated number...could someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: How many times are you going to ask this question? You've already asked this and other related questions in other threads and received answers to those questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to place them in an array and access the member of the array that your generated random number tells you to.

Android generally means java so:

```
import java.util.Random

Random rand = new Random();


String[] myarray = new String[]{st1, st2, st3, st4, st5, st6, st7, st8, st9};
int myrand = rand.nextInt(8);
System.out.println(myarray[myrand]);
```

Forgive me any minor syntax errors, it's been a while since I've programmed in Java.

Comment: sorry, it is in android programming.

Comment: Would you happen to have a simple example in regular code?  Ie:  How to call one in droid?  Thanks so much!

Comment: I've updated the post under the assumption that you're using java, which is the most common language on the Android platform.

Comment: Awesome thank you!  Do I need a way to call the strings from my strings.xml file?  I have them all listed and labeled in there, but I have errors under all of my st strings...DO i need to have R.string.st1, R.string.st2, etc...?

Comment: The example provided assumes that st1..st9 all exist as String objects.  If you have them as something different than that then naturally you'll need to convert them.

Answer (score 1):

put your strings into an array, pick a random integer between zero and the length of the string array, and use the number to index into the array.

Comment: I don't have an array though, I have a bunch of individual strings I wrote up all labeled something differently =x

Comment: yeah, I realized that right after I posted, that's why I edited my answer. it's not possible to use a string array then?

Comment: Sorry I am not too familiar with arrays in android, could you please show me an example?

Comment: you could maybe pick a random i between 0 and 8, and access variable ("st" + str(i+1))? sorry for dumb question but I know nothing about android

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of strings defined in strings.xml then it will look more like this:

```
import java.util.Random

Random rand = new Random();

int[] myarray = new int[]{
   R.strings.my_string_1,
   R.strings.my_string_2,
   R.strings.my_string_3,
   R.strings.my_string_4
};
int myrand = rand.nextInt(myarray.length-1);
System.out.println(getText(myarray[myrand]));
```

This assumes that you're doing this in an `Activity` where the `getText` method is available.